# "SimpleAudioEngine has not been declared" error when trying to enable music pausing in Cocos2D-X

Tags: audio, cocos2d-x, appdelegate, simpleaudioengine

So using Cocos2D-X, in the `AppDelegate.cpp` file, I uncomment the line:

```
SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
```

so that my audio will be paused when the app is exited. However, when I do this, I get the error stated in the title. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer from Dmitry Fomin is correct, or after you put

```
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

you can use

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems to me that you forgot to add declaration of SimpleAudioEngine. Add this lines to AppDelegate.cpp:

```
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"

using namespace CocosDenshion;
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleAudioEngine.h` header file contain `SimpleAudioEngine` class so add

```
#include "SimpleAudioEngine.h"
```

in your file. `SimpleAudioEngine` is in CocosDenshion namespace so you can use

```
using namespace CocosDenshion;

SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
```

or by

```
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
```